# TestNG - Parallel Methods Not Working

Tags: testing, automation, testng

I have a testNG suite where I want all methods in all classes I've specified to be run:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="20" name="SmokeTestSuite" parallel="methods">

  <test name="Test1" group-by-instances="true" junit="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="Class1"/>
      <class name="Class2"/> 
      <class name="Class3"/>
    </classes>
  </test>

</suite>
```

However this doesn't run all the methods, its doing it one class at a time.

If i write my suite as the following it works - however having to duplicate code in this way isn't appealing/very time consuming.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="20" name="SmokeTestSuite" parallel="tests">

  <test name="Test1" group-by-instances="true" junit="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="Class1"/>
        <methods>
           <include name="myAutoTest1"/>
        </methods>
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Test2" group-by-instances="true" junit="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="Class1"/>
        <methods>
           <include name="myAutoTest2"/>
        </methods>
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Test3" group-by-instances="true" junit="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="Class1"/>
        <methods>
           <include name="myAutoTest3"/>
        </methods>
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Test4" group-by-instances="true" junit="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="Class2"/>
        <methods>
           <include name="myAutoTest4"/>
        </methods>
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Test5" group-by-instances="true" junit="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="Class3"/>
        <methods>
           <include name="myAutoTest5"/>
        </methods>
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Test6" group-by-instances="true" junit="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="Class3"/>
        <methods>
           <include name="myAutoTest6"/>
        </methods>
    </classes>
  </test>

</suite>
```

Any ideas to why this could be occuring?

Thanks

Comment: Is `junit="true"` mandatory? Is it working as expected without it?

Comment: No tests run without it.

Comment: I suppose they are junit tests. But why not converting to testng tests if you use testng as runner?

Comment: The utilise parrallel execution. JUnit is not working as we expect hence want to try TestNG to achieve.

Comment: I suppose something is wrong with the junit support of testng. But why not  trying to convert your junit tests into testng ones? Parallel should work with TestNG tests.

Comment: I am also thinking this - tests need to be converted to TestNG. This in essence seems simple, however I'm picking up on some old code that uses another framework. So class constructors contains a argument constructor that is required i.e. I can't implement the zero args constrcutor TestNG wants

Comment: Have a look on @Factory http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories